# Block PHP Webpage except through Redirect from PHP webpage using Session Variables

Tags: php, html, redirect, session-variables

I am trying to block access to my webpage except it is accessed via a successful button click on a verification page.

The backend of the verification has been handled and it works as expected. I currently have two blocks of PHP code which work for different purposes of the two I a trying to achieve.

The first block works to block the page and redirect it to the verification page if a session variable has not been set and the second block works to redirect from the verification page to the homepage when the form is submitted and validated succesfully.

However, I cannot get a PHP block of code that works to block the main page unless redirected from the verification page and to also allow redirection to itself/the main page when verification is complete from the verificatio, page.

I have tried the following, which works to redirect to the main page, except when the absolute path for that page is typed in, it is still accessible:

```
<?php
    session_start(); // Start the session
    // Check if the current page is not already capacityindex.php
    if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) !== 'capacityindex.php') {
        if ((isset($_SESSION['display_page2']) && $_SESSION['display_page2'] === TRUE) || isset($_POST['Submitted'])) {
            // Keep displaying capacityindex.php
            //header('Location:capacityindex.php');
        } else {
            header('Location:capacityverification.php');
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        // Current page is already index.php, no need for redirection
    }
    ?>
```

And I have tried the following, which works to block the main page and redirect to the verification page:

```
<?php
    session_start(); // Start the session
    // Check if the current page is not already capacityindex.php
    // Check if the current page is index.php
    $isIndexPage = (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) === 'capacityindex.php');

    // If this is the index.php page and access is not allowed, redirect
    if ($isIndexPage && !isset($_SESSION['display_page2']) && $_SESSION['display_page2'] !== TRUE) {
        header('Location:capacityverification.php');
        exit;
    }
    ?>
```

I have also tried combining the two solutions and no combination I have tried works:

```
<?php
    session_start(); // Start the session
    // Check if the current page is not already capacityindex.php
    // Check if the current page is index.php
    $isIndexPage = (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) === 'capacityindex.php');
    $isNotIndexPage = (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) !== 'capacityindex.php');

    if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) !== 'capacityindex.php') {
        if ((isset($_SESSION['display_page2']) && $_SESSION['display_page2'] === TRUE) || isset($_POST['Submitted'])) {
            // Keep displaying capacityindex.php
            //header('Location:capacityindex.php');
        } else {
            header('Location:capacityverification.php');
            exit;
        }
    }

    // If this is the index.php page and access is not allowed, redirect
    if ($isIndexPage && !isset($_SESSION['display_page2']) && $_SESSION['display_page2'] !== TRUE) {
        header('Location:capacityverification.php');
        exit;
        // if this is not index.php page and access is allowed, Keep displaying capacityindex.php
    }
    ?>
```

And for additional reference, this is how the session variable is being set in another file:

```
<?php
session_start(); // Start the session

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['Submitted'])) {
        $_SESSION['display_page2'] = true;
        // Return a success response to the AJAX request
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success'));
    } else {
        // Return an error response to the AJAX request
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error'));
    }
} else {
    // Return an error response for invalid request method
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'not post error'));
}
?>
```

Comment: You can't really tell how your page was called. Anything that's done by the button-click code can be spoofed by the user.

Comment: _"except when the absolute path for that page is typed in"_ - can you please explain what that means? How is this any different, from the user following a link to that same URL from somewhere?

Comment: `&& !isset($_SESSION['display_page2']) && $_SESSION['display_page2'] !== TRUE` - what's not _set_ to begin with, certainly doesn't need checking for not being true afterwards.

Comment: @CBroe If the site or other sites use tracking cookies or tools like Google Analytics you can often tell when someone lands on your page from another site (and which site) or just by typing in the URL directly. Unless they use `rel=noreferrer` on the link. That's probably what OP means--when someone types the URL directly he can't block/redirect it, but he wants to.

Comment: @TylerH but if someone typed in the URL directly, then the session value that was supposed to be set when they visit another page first, should not exist. If that's all they want here, to make users go visit their page X before page Y can be accessed - then it should not matter whether they arrived on Y by clicking a link from anywhere other than X, or typed Y in themselves - in both cases, the session value should not be set, and therefor access be denied.

Comment: @CBroe yes, what Tyler said is correct. I want to block and then redirect to a verification page if the user did not land on the main page from the verification page.

Comment: @Barmar when the button is clicked, an API is called, and an AWS lambda code is processed. When that code returns 200 which is a success I have another AJAX request that sets a server side variable (display_page2) like in the final code and that is how I know the button click is successful

Comment: What's with all these `if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])` checks? If you want to protect _one_ single "page" (and "page" and "individual script file" appear to be the same thing here), then the code that checks if the necessary value exist in the session, only needs to go into _one_ script file, and then you don't need to check which one you are in any more.

Comment: @CBroe I agree with you--just making a guess at what OP meant :-)

Comment: @CBroe Edit: Yes what you just explained is correct and redirecting to the first page works like you have explained, but in that case, after the session variable has been set when the user finishes on the first page, then no redirect to the second page happens even when the session variable is set

Comment: @CBroe Also, the provided code only goes in one file. I just provided variations of what I have tried. The last code snippet is how the session variable is set, and this is done in another file

Comment: Why wouldn't the session variable exist if someone types the URL? The session variable is created when you go to the page the first time, which could be through the required redirection. It doesn't go away unless something explicitly deletes it.